# Store Data in MSTest TestContext or other way to store data during TestRun

Tags: c#, mstest

I their a way to store Data global in the TestContext of MsTest? Or another mechanism to store Data during a TestRun?

I want to read a string from a Rest-Resource at Assembly Initialize and store it somewhere to get access to it during my custom implementation of TestMehtod.

Comment: There are many ways to do this. Some more beutiful than others. What sort of data do you actually need stored? 

It would be nice with a bit more information if someone is supposed to help you.

Comment: Nothing special, some strings and I am happy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 solutions that come to mind.

### RunSettings

The first is a more integrated solution with Visual Studio and MSTest's [RunSettings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/test/configure-unit-tests-by-using-a-dot-runsettings-file?view=vs-2019) file. Within a RunSettings file, which is defined in an XML structure, you have predefined `<TestRunParameters>` which can be accessed and set within methods or classes decorated by an MSTest decorator (e.g. `[AssemblyInitialize]`, `[TestClass]`, etc.). Within these decorated methods or classes, you of course have access to a `TestContext` object, and within this `TestContext` object, you can get or set the key-value pairs defined in your `<TestRunParameters>` by using `TestContext.Properties`.

For example, say you have a RunSettings file,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RunSettings>
    <TestRunParameters>
        <Parameter name="Name" value="Dan" />
    </TestRunParameters>
</RunSettings>
```

you can do this within your test class:

```
[TestClass]
public class Configuration 
{
    [ClassInitialize]
    public static void ClassInitialize(TestContext testContext) 
    {
        Console.Write(testContext.Properties["Name"]); // Outputs "Dan"

        // The TestContext object will be modified and the updated value 
        // will be ready the next time it's retrieved
        testContext.Properties["Name"] = "John"; 
    }
}
```

### Static Classes

Alternatively, you could have a static class whose sole purpose is to initialize and store your strings.